# Android in Car Audio

Tags: android

Is there any company has successfully deploy Android OS in car audio industry? And any SW arch of android in Car audio available in the web?

Answer (score 0):

The only company I know of that's working on Android in automobiles is Stitcher. I'm sure there are others, I just don't know them.

Comment: I'm sorry but question does not related to programming issues. You'd better ask somewhere in other places. StackExchange - I suppose is right place for that